# MySQL limit maximum rows for same "user" value

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb, acid

How can I limit in MySQL maximum rows for the same "user" value?

For example, I have table with columns

```
id | user | data
```

and I would like to limit maximum rows count to 5 for each user (the same "user" value).

My idea is to use transactions (InnoDB):

```
start transaction
insert row with user = "XXX"
count rows, where user = "XXX"
if count < 5 commit else rollback
```

Is my idea good or exist also another (better) solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's ok, You may want to make a

```
select count(1) from table where user='XXX'
```

and check the count before performing the insert.

Comment: No, I **must to check** the count after inserting. Because another insert process can between my count and insert.

Comment: You stated that you are uaing transaction. So if inconsistency happens you can't commit.

Comment: The real count value (number of rows) can increase during transaction, so I can have count value 4, but the real count number is 5... So I must count after insert.

Comment: Set the transaction level to SERIALIZABLE if possible.

Comment: I tried to change mysql config with `transaction-isolation = SERIALIZABLE` but its not working. I have dirty read....

Answer (score 0):

This could be done by using special "dual" table:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, user, data)
    SELECT 1, 'XXX', 'somedata' 
      FROM dual 
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT user
           FROM t
          WHERE user = 'XXX'
       GROUP BY user 
         HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
     )
```